# Bazaar - changing email in revisions history

Tags: email, bazaar, revisions

does anybody knows if it's possible to change commiter email address in Bazaar revisions history?

I've setup an email address with "bzr whoami" command, but now I'd like to change it in way that also my email in old commits will be replaced with the new one.

Regards,
K.

Comment: @jberg: There's a lot of usernames like CCC or DDD, so I would assume that this user created his username in the same vein. Not everyone will have heard about the KKK, especially if the user isn't from the US .

Comment: Vote to close, move to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

No, the history in Bazaar is immutable. If you change your user-id then you change the entire history of your project.